# How to get access to data in Github Repo with Nodejs Express

Tags: node.js, express, github, web-scraping, fetch

I'm currently trying to get COVID-19 from the `Covid Data Repository by Johns Hopkins.` https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

The repo get updated with new data every 24h, and they upload the data in `.csv` files daily.

My question would be: How to get access to the latest data from my Web App with Nodejs? **Scraping** or there's an easy way that I'm missing?

MERN Stack

Answer (score 1):

Github API might be of some help here but there seems to be no way you can read the contents modified through a commit. However, you verify which file is modified in a commit. Using this name, you can render the raw file in a browser which might be easier to read in CSV format.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/04-06-2020.csv

Answer (score -1):

You are missing out the easy way. you can retrieve the csv files easily with superface sdk by iterating the day as the filename.  For example - lets retrieve 01-01-2021.csv

```
npm install @superfaceai/one-sdk

npx @superfaceai/cli install vcs/single-file-content
```

```js
const { SuperfaceClient } = require("@superfaceai/one-sdk");

const sdk = new SuperfaceClient();

async function run() {
  // Load the installed profile
  const profile = await sdk.getProfile("vcs/single-file-content");

  // Use the profile
  const result = await profile.getUseCase("SingleFileContent").perform({
    owner: "CSSEGISandData",
    repo: "COVID-19",
    path: "csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/01-01-2021.csv",
    ref: "1f0e048",
  });

  console.log(result.unwrap());
}

run();
```